# Calculate the time difference between of two rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with column StartDate, I want to calculate the time difference between two consecutive record.

Thanks.

---

@ Mark Byers and  @ Yahia, I have request table as requestId, startdate

```
requestId    startdate               
1            2011-10-16 13:15:56
2            2011-10-16 13:15:59
3            2011-10-16 13:15:59
4            2011-10-16 13:16:02
5            2011-10-16 13:18:07
```

and i want to know what is the time difference between requestid 1 & 2, 2 & 3, 3 & 4 and so on. i know i will need self join on table, but i am not getting correct on clause.

Comment: Consecutive according to what field? Can you give an example of what you want?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To achieve what you are asking try the following (UPDATE after edit from OP):

```
SELECT A.requestid, A.starttime, (B.starttime - A.starttime) AS timedifference
FROM MyTable A INNER JOIN MyTable B ON B.requestid = (A.requestid + 1)
ORDER BY A.requestid ASC
```

IF `requestid` is not consecutive then you can use

```
SELECT A.requestid, A.starttime, (B.starttime - A.starttime) AS timedifference
FROM MyTable A CROSS JOIN MyTable B
WHERE B.requestid IN (SELECT MIN (C.requestid) FROM MyTable C WHERE C.requestid > A.requestid)
ORDER BY A.requestid ASC
```

Comment: Second purpose could be written with `starttime` instead of `requestid`!!

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is correct but gives the difference of numbers.
As an example if I have the following 2 timestamps:

```
2014-06-09 09:48:15
2014-06-09 09:50:11
```

The difference is given as 196. This is simply 5011 - 4815.
In order to get the time difference, you may modify the script as follows:

```
SELECT A.requestid, A.starttime, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.starttime,B.starttime) AS timedifference 
FROM MyTable A INNER JOIN MyTable B ON B.requestid = (A.requestid + 1) 
ORDER BY A.requestid ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, grd.startdate, grd1.startdate) as TD FROM myTable A 
inner join myTable B on A.requestId = B.requestId - 1 and 
A.startdate >= '2019-07-01' order by TD desc
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use the [`LEAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) window function to get the value from the next row (where next is defined as the row having the next higher `requestId`):

```sql
SELECT *, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startdate, LEAD(startdate) OVER (ORDER BY requestId))) AS diff
FROM mytable
```

Output for your sample data:

```
requestId   startdate               diff
1           2011-10-16 13:15:56     00:00:03
2           2011-10-16 13:15:59     00:00:00
3           2011-10-16 13:15:59     00:00:03
4           2011-10-16 13:16:02     00:02:05
5           2011-10-16 13:18:07     null
```

Demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cau8uRV1MHQXrWozYt5Qvg/1)