# Time between two non consecutive rows? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

I've looked here [Calculate the time difference between of two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows/7937333#7937333).

I modified the code here:

`SELECT A.Test_ID, B.TestDate - A.TestDate AS DaysBetweenTests
FROM Exams A
JOIN Exams B ON B.Test_ID = A.Test_ID
WHERE
(SELECT B.Test_ID FROM B.Exams 
ORDER BY Animal_ID, B.TestDate LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)`

This query isn't complete. I'm trying to calculate the days between **TestDate** with the next **TestDate** for the same `Animal_ID`. The problem here is that an `Animal_ID` **TestDate** is not directly consecutive with `Test_ID`. I can't use `Test_ID +1`.

Sample Exams table:

```
Test_ID  |  TestDate  |  Animal_ID
1           2013-01-01   100
2           2007-06-18   162
3           2013-02-01   100
4           2013-04-16   100
```

The **TestDate** for a single `Animal_ID` is always increasing in order, thus a higher `Test_ID number`.

I'm having trouble with the subquery.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Note that dates should be stored using a DATE data type.

Comment: It is stored in DATE type. It's in yyyy-mm-dd format, I just typed them in mm/dd/yy format to make it easier to read.

Comment: ... if you happen to hail from a relatively small part of the attached map... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query repeats the subquery that determines the next test date. You don't necessarily need to do that in production; it just helps to see the data when you're figuring things out.

```
SELECT T1.Animal_ID, 
       T1.TestDate,
       (SELECT min(TestDate)
        FROM Exams
        WHERE Animal_ID = T1.Animal_ID
          AND TestDate > T1.TestDate
        GROUP BY Animal_ID
        ) AS Next_TestDate, 
        datediff((SELECT min(TestDate)
                  FROM Exams
                  WHERE Animal_ID = T1.Animal_ID
                    AND TestDate > T1.TestDate
                  GROUP BY Animal_ID
                  ), T1.TestDate) AS Elapsed_Days
FROM Exams T1
ORDER BY Animal_ID, TestDate;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm currently trying to convert this to MS Access sql as well. (Looking into the datediff() function. I think I just need to put in "d" for the first criteria, then insert the datediff query.)

Comment: Converted to MS Access SQL in another file.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
t.*,
coalesce(timestampdiff(day, @prevDate, if(@prevAnimal = Animal_ID, TestDate, @prevDate)), 0) as timedifference_in_days,
@prevAnimal := Animal_ID,
@prevDate := TestDate
from
t
, (select @prevDate := null, @prevAnimal := null) as var_init
order by Animal_ID, TestDate
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/588ca/5/0)</kbd>

---

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`Test_ID` int, `TestDate` date, `Animal_ID` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`Test_ID`, `TestDate`, `Animal_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, '2013-01-01', 100),
    (2, '2007-06-18', 162),
    (3, '2013-02-01', 100),
    (4, '2013-04-16', 100)
;
```

Output:

```
| TEST_ID |                        TESTDATE | ANIMAL_ID | TIMEDIFFERENCE_IN_DAYS | @PREVANIMAL := ANIMAL_ID | @PREVDATE := TESTDATE |
|---------|---------------------------------|-----------|------------------------|--------------------------|-----------------------|
|       1 |  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       100 |                      0 |                      100 |            2013-01-01 |
|       3 | February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       100 |                     31 |                      100 |            2013-02-01 |
|       4 |    April, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       100 |                     74 |                      100 |            2013-04-16 |
|       2 |     June, 18 2007 00:00:00+0000 |       162 |                      0 |                      162 |            2007-06-18 |
```