# Select Status That Last for More Than 1 Second

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a problem looks simple, but I could not find the solution.

So, I have got a table with two cols like this:

```
Time               Status

00:00:00.111       Off

00:00:00.222       On

00:00:00.345       On

00:00:01.555       On

00:00:01.666       Off

00:00:02.222       On

00:00:02.422       On

00:00:02.622       Off

00:00:05.888       Off

00:00:05.999       Off
```

I want to select all statuses of On which lasted for more than 1 second,
in this example, I want the sequence:

```
00:00:00.222       On

00:00:00.345       On

00:00:01.555       On
```

Could you guys give me any clue? Many thanks!

Comment: What are the data types? Which version of SQL/MySQL is it? I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows

Comment: Between the first two of your desired result it's less than one second. Why?

Comment: Thanks, Marekful. I meant that the status of On lasted from 00:00:00.222 to 00:00:01.555, the time duration is larger than one second.

Comment: Then your description is not accurate. You want to select all consecutive On status rows where the elapsed time between the first and last row is more than one second and is followed by an Off. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted, I will modify the the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `GROUP BY` and `SUM` can not do this on your current dataset, so my idea is to add a helper column:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable(
`time` DATETIME,
status CHAR(3),
helperCol INT
);
```

The helperCol is an INT and will be set as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE setHelperCol() 
BEGIN
  DECLARE finished,v_helperCol INT;
  DECLARE status CHAR(3);
  DECLARE ts DATETIME;
  DECLARE CURSOR st FOR SELECT `time`,status,helperCol FROM someTable WHERE helperCol IS NOT NULL; -- Handy for re-use: No need to go over all data, so you can save the helperCol as permanent value.
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
  SELECT @maxVal:=MAX(helperCol) FROM helperCol;

  SET finished=0;
  SET helperCol=@maxVal;
  IF(!helperCol>0) SET helperCol=1;
  OPEN st;
  FETCH ts,status,v_helperCol FROM st;
  WHILE(finished=0) DO
    IF(status='Off') v_helperCol=v_helperCol+1;
    UPDATE someTable SET helperCol=v_helperCol WHERE `time`=ts; -- Assuming `time` is unique;
    FETCH ts,status,v_helperCol FROM st;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE st;
END;
```

Execute the procedure and the result is:

```
Time               Status  helperCol
00:00:00.111       Off      2
00:00:00.222       On       2
00:00:00.345       On       2
00:00:01.555       On       2
00:00:01.666       Off      3
00:00:02.222       On       3
00:00:02.422       On       3
00:00:02.622       Off      4
```

This can now be grouped and processed:

```
SELECT MAX(`time`)-MIN(`time`) AS diffTime
FROM someTable
WHERE status='ON'
GROUP BY helperCol
HAVING MAX(`time`)-MIN(`time`)>1;
```

The result of that is (you need to search for the correct `datetime` functions to apply in the `MAX-MIN` part):

```
1.333
```

**Alternative:**

You can also process the `MAX-MIN` in the stored procedure, but that would not be efficiently repeatable as the helperColumn solution is.

Comment: Hi, Norbert, many thanks for your answer, the solution looks quite good. However, in my situation, I would have a huge table and I need to select all such status lasted for more than one second. I will think about it further

Comment: I took the large table into account by making the procedure incremental: When you add data, the procedure only has to process the new part. By adding an index on `helperCol` it will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.time start
     , MIN(c.time) end
     , TIMEDIFF(MIN(c.time),a.time) duration
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*,  COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.time <= x.time GROUP BY time ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*,  COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.time <= x.time GROUP BY time ) b
    ON b.status = a.status
   AND b.rank = a.rank - 1
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*,  COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.time <= x.time GROUP BY time ) c
    ON c.rank >= a.rank
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*,  COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.time <= x.time GROUP BY time ) d
    ON d.status = c.status 
   AND d.rank = c.rank + 1
 WHERE b.rank IS NULL
   AND d.rank IS NULL
   AND a.status = 1
 GROUP
    BY a.time
HAVING duration >= 1;
```

Another, faster, method might be along these lines - unfortunately I don't think the data types and functions in my version of MySQL support fractions of a second, so this is probably a little bit wrong (there may also be a logical error)...

```
SELECT time
     , status 
     , cumulative
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN @prev = status THEN @i:=@i+duration ELSE @i:=0 END cumulative
            , @prev:=status
         FROM 
            ( SELECT x.*
                   , TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(y.time))-TIME_TO_SEC(x.time) duration 
                FROM my_table x 
                JOIN my_table y 
                  ON y.time > x.time 
               GROUP 
                  BY x.time
            ) n
        ORDER 
           BY time
     ) a
 WHERE cumulative >= 1
   AND status = 1;
```