# MySQL timestamp differences between two rows large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Transactions table with over 2,500,000 rows and three columns (that are relevant): id, company_id, and created_at. id identifies the transaction, company_id identifies which company received it, created_at is a timestamp with the time that transaction was performed.

What I want is to get a list of the differences between every consecutive pair of transactions of a given company. In other words, if my table goes:

```
 id | company_id | created_at
------------------------------
 01 |     ab     | 2016/01/02
 02 |     ab     | 2016/01/03
 03 |     cd     | 2016/01/03
 04 |     ab     | 2016/01/03
 05 |     cd     | 2016/01/04
 06 |     ab     | 2016/01/05
```

(Note that there may be an arbitrary number of transactions of other companies between two consecutive transaction of a given company.)

Then I want the output to be:

```
 diff | company_id
-------------------
  01  |     ab
  00  |     ab
  01  |     cd
  02  |     ab
```

(I wrote the created_at and diff values in days, but that's just for ease of visualisation.)

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows) but it was too slow.

--EDIT:

"This" is:

```
SELECT (B.created_at - A.created_at) AS diff, A.company_id
FROM Transactions A CROSS JOIN Transactions B
WHERE B.id IN (SELECT MIN (C.id) FROM Transactions C WHERE C.id > A.id AND C.company_id = A.company_id)
ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to click your link.

Comment: Edited it to add more information

Comment: I think most efficient will be to write stored procedure with cursor and order it by id. Cross join is a killer...

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't what that means or how to do that.

Comment: What is the data distribution approximately? # of companies, # of entries per company, ...? If the number of entries per company is high, I suspect wallycz's proposed solution would be the most efficient.

Comment: Approximately 1,000 companies, with entries ranging from 1 to order of 100,000. I'm not sure what wallycz's proposed solution actually is, though.

Comment: Your example is wrong, since unique number of pairs is N(N-1)/2. There are four "ab" in your example, thus there will be 4(4-1)/2 = 6 pairs, not 3

Comment: I'd meant 'consecutive pairs,' edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a result like the one it looks like you're expecting, I will sometimes make use of MySQL user-defined variables, and have MySQL perform the processing of the rows "in order", so I can compare the current row to values from the previous row.

For this to run efficiently, we'll want an appropriate index, to avoid an expensive "Using filesort" operation. (We're going to need the rows in `company_id` order, then by `id` order, so those will be the first two columns in the index. While we're at it, we might just as well include the `created_at` column and make it a covering index.

```
... ON Transactions (company_id, id, created_at)
```

Then we can try a query like this:

```
SELECT t.diff
     , t.company_id
  FROM (
         SELECT IF(r.company_id = @pv_company_id, r.created_at - @pv_created_at, NULL) AS diff
              , IF(r.company_id = @pv_company_id, 1, 0) AS include_
              , @pv_company_id := r.company_id          AS company_id
              , @pv_created_at := r.created_at          AS created_at
           FROM (SELECT @pv_company_id := NULL, @pv_created_at := NULL) i
          CROSS
           JOIN Transactions r
          ORDER
             BY r.company_id
              , r.id
       ) t
 WHERE t.include_
```

The MySQL Reference Manual explicitly warns against using user-defined variables like this within a statement. But the behavior we observe in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5 is consistent. (The big problem is that some future version of MySQL could use a different execution plan.)

The inline view aliased as `i` is just to initialize a couple of user-defined variables. We could just as easily do that as a separate step, before we run our query. But I like to include the initialization right in the statement itself, so I don't need a separate SELECT/SET statement.

MySQL accesses the Transactions table, and processes the `ORDER BY` first, ordering the rows from `Transactions` in (company_id,id) order.  (We prefer to have this done via an index, rather than via an expensive "Using filesort" operation, which is why we want that index defined, with `company_id` and `id` as the leading columns.

The "trick" is saving the values from the current row into user-defined variables.  When processing the next row, the values from the previous row are available in the user-defined variables, for performing comparisons (is the current row for the same company_id as the previous row?) and for performing a calculation (the difference between the `created_at` values of the two rows.

Based on the usage of the subtraction operation, I'm assuming that the `created_at` columns is integer/numeric. That is, I'm assuming that `created_at` is *not* `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, because we don't use the subtraction operation to find a difference.

```
SELECT a
     , b
     , a - b                  AS `subtraction`
     , DATEDIFF(a,b)          AS `datediff`
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,b,a) AS `tsdiff`
  FROM ( SELECT DATE('2015-02-17') AS a
              , DATE('2015-01-16') AS b
       ) t
```

returns:

```
a           b           subtraction  datediff  tsdiff  
----------  ----------  -----------  --------  ------
2015-02-17  2015-01-16          101        32      32
```

(The subtraction operation doesn't throw an error. But what it returns may be unexpected. In this example, it returns the difference between two integer values `20150217` and `20150116`, which is *not* the number of days between the two `DATE` expressions.)

**EDIT**

I notice that the original query includes an `ORDER BY`. If you need the rows returned in a specific order, you can include that column in the inline view query, and use an `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

```
SELECT t.diff
     , t.company_id
  FROM (
         SELECT IF(r.company_id = @pv_company_id, r.created_at - @pv_created_at, NULL) AS diff
              , IF(r.company_id = @pv_company_id, 1, 0) AS include_
              , @pv_company_id := r.company_id          AS company_id
              , @pv_created_at := r.created_at          AS created_at
              , r.id                                    AS id
           FROM (SELECT @pv_company_id := NULL, @pv_created_at := NULL) i
          CROSS
           JOIN Transactions r
          ORDER
             BY r.company_id
              , r.id
       ) t
 WHERE t.include_
 ORDER BY t.id
```

Sorry, there's no getting around a "Using filesort" for the `ORDER BY` on the outer query.

Comment: Repeating here some notes already included in this answer: Don't use subtraction operation on `DATE` expressions; that won't return the result you expect. e.g. `SELECT ('2015-02-17'+INTERVAL 0 DAY) - ('2015-01-16'+INTERVAL 0 DAY)` returns 101 not 32. To return a difference in days, use `DATEFIFF` function. And the MySQL Reference Manual *explicitly* warns against using user-defined variables in this manner... "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is *undefined*.".  Reference: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    t1.company_id,
    t2.created_at - t1.created_at as diff
FROM Transactions t1
LEFT JOIN Transactions t2
    on t2.created_at > t1.created_at
    and t2.company_id = t1.company_id
```

Comment: Beyond the typos in the query itself, this is not going to return the correct results as the left join will return more than one resulting record per row.

Comment: @randyh22, what makes you think so?

Comment: I want the differences between only consecutive pairs, not every possible pair.

Comment: create a table like the one provided by the OP and run your query and see what results you get. You are going to get a 1 to many result which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cursor functionality. If you open a cursor you slide every row and every two lines fetched you make a difference. I think this method is more efficient because slide all the rows of table instead make a join over 2  and half million.

Comment: Based on the sample data provided by the OP, the rows being compared are not always consecutive in the table. You can't always compare two consecutive rows in the table.

Comment: Can you actually write out the code for this? I don't have any idea of how to do it and the tutorials I've been able to find haven't been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too.

```
SELECT company_id, 
  (SELECT DATEDIFF(created_at,TR.created_at) 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE id > TR.id AND company_id = TR.company_id LIMIT 0,1) AS diff
FROM transactions AS TR
HAVING diff is not null
```

Comment: This has been running for ten minutes and still no results.

Comment: With 2.5M transactions, it is going to take a while. Especially if your company_id and created_at fields are not indexed.