# Find difference between sequential rows mysql, no row ID

Tags: mysql

Objective: get the difference between the value in a row and the value in the next row (I'm using MySQL). Say we have the table "events":

```
step:                timestamp:

Leave for store      1400000000
Buy hamburgers       1400000002
Big party            1400000005
```

So the result we'd expect is:

```
2
3
```

Complication 1: My table *doesn't* have an ID column, so I can't do this:

```
select (e2.timestamp - e1.timestamp)
from events e1, events e2
where (e1.id + 1) = e2.id
```

Complication 2: I'm using a database connection (Splunk) that won't allow me to create or alter temporary tables (otherwise I'd just add an id column). Am I hosed?

thank you!

Comment: You don't need an ID column, but you need some column that can be used to order the rows. MySQL doesn't provide any built-in ordering of tables.

Comment: Should they be ordered by timestamp?

Comment: They are indeed ordered by timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a user variable to hold the timestamp from the previous line.

```
SELECT step, timestamp - @prevtime AS diff, @prevtime := timestamp
FROM events
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevtime := 0) AS x
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Barmar! I'll be able to test this in just a minute. How exactly does this work, though? Specifically, what does the SELECT in the CROSS JOIN accomplish?

Comment: It's needed to initialize the variable. You could also do it using `SET @prevtime = 0` before the query, but I prefer to keep the query self-contained.

Comment: @Bamar this worked, thank you! Additionally, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows?rq=1) used syntax I was a little more familiar with (as a beginner), and I thought it was really clever. I ended up implementing it.

Comment: That method works, but the join may be very slow for a large table.

Comment: Works nicely, thanks! Small tip if your data contains datetimes instead of timestamps: use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).