# Time differences between row in google big query

Tags: mysql, syntax, google-bigquery, datediff

I'm currently attempting to calculate the timestamp differences between rows in google big query attached is the sample table I am using to test the code [image: sample table].

I am using this code

```
SELECT 
  A.row,
  A.issue.updated_at,
 (B.issue.updated_at - A.issue.updated_at) AS timedifference
FROM [icxmedia-servers:icx_metrics.gh_zh_data_production] A
INNER JOIN [icxmedia-servers:icx_metrics.gh_zh_data_production] B
  ON B.row = (A.row + 1)
WHERE issue.number==6 and issue.name=="archer"
ORDER BY A.requestid ASC
```

Referenced from this question [Calculate the time difference between of two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a `JOIN`, this is more naturally expressed using analytic functions. The documentation for [analytic functions with standard SQL in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions) explains how analytic functions work and what the syntax is. As an example, if you wanted to take successive differences in `x` values where the order is determined by column `y`, you could do:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT
    x,
    y
  FROM UNNEST([9, 3, 4, 7]) AS x WITH OFFSET y)
SELECT
  x,
  x - LAG(x) OVER (ORDER BY y) AS x_diff
FROM T;
```

Note that to run this in BigQuery, you need to uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options" to enable standard SQL. The `WITH T` clause is simply setting up some data for the example.

For your specific case, you would probably want a query such as:

```
SELECT
  row,
  issue.updated_at,
  issue.updated_at - LAG(issue.updated_at) OVER (ORDER BY issue.updated_at) AS timedifference
FROM `icxmedia-servers.icx_metrics.gh_zh_data_production`
WHERE issue.number = 6
  AND issue.name = "archer"
ORDER BY requestid ASC;
```

If you want to determine differences in `updated_at` outside of just a single issue number, you could use a `PARTITION BY` clause as well. For example:

```
SELECT
  row,
  issue.name,
  issue.number,
  issue.updated_at,
  issue.updated_at - LAG(issue.updated_at) OVER (
      PARTITION BY issue.number
      ORDER BY issue.updated_at) AS timedifference
FROM `icxmedia-servers.icx_metrics.gh_zh_data_production`
ORDER BY requestid ASC;
```

Comment: I tried to do something equal to your sugestion - issue.updated_at - LAG(issue.updated_at) OVER (ORDER BY issue.updated_at) AS timedifference - in my query but I received an error - Missing function in Analytic Expression. Have you right about it possibility?

Comment: Please create a separate question with an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to get a difference between rows, but the values are integers and not timestamp. The LAG function works fine alone. But if I try to do the subtraction that you suggested I receive the warning - Missing function in Analytic Expression. IS the same question with different columns and values.

Comment: Please create a *separate question*. Do not keep asking on this comment thread.

Comment: I just have the same question but I have created a new question like you suggested me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695274/differences-between-row-in-google-big-query