# Differences between row in google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag

I'm currently attempting to calculate differences between rows in google big query. I actually have a working query.

```
 SELECT
    id, record_time, level, lag,
    (level - lag) as diff
 FROM (
   SELECT
      id, record_time, level, 
      LAG(level) OVER (ORDER BY id, record_time) as lag
   FROM (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        TABLE_QUERY(MY_TABLES))
   ORDER BY
      1, 2 ASC
    )
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
 ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

But I'm working with big data and sometimes I have memory limit warning that does not let me execute the query. So, I would like to understand why I cant do an optimized query like bellow. I think it will allow work with more records without memory limit warning.

```
   SELECT
      id, record_time, level,
      level - LAG(level, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id, record_time) as diff
   FROM (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        TABLE_QUERY(MY_TABLES))
   ORDER BY
      1, 2 ASC
```

This kind of function `level - LAG(level, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id, record_time) as diff,` when the query is executed returns the error

> Missing function in Analytic Expression

on Big Query.

I also tried to put `( )` into this function but it does not work as well.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Also I think you have a trailing comma before 'FROM (' and a missing ')' at the end.

Comment: first query in your question makes no sense at all. usually nonsense stuff fails! so trying to improve it makes not much sense either. I recommend you rather to explain what you are trying to achieve by your first query so we will help you to fix it

Comment: as of `I have memory limit warning that does not let me execute the query` - just remove ORDER BY statements!

Comment: @NhanNguyen, you are right, here it is a query example, but it is working as expected, I added a ')' and removed the comma.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, I want to found the difference between rows. Each row has a timestamp and represents some level for that DateTime. I can see if the level is going up or down if it was ordered. The first query adds an extra column with the last level by function LAG and then I calculate the diff between next levels. I'm working with big data, and I'm with the memory limit warning because of the LAG and the multiples SELECTS. The problem is not the ORDER BY statements. So, I try to execute the diff with LAG function at the same time with fewer SELECTS. But it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

It works fine for me. Maybe you forgot to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)? Here is an example:

```
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, TIMESTAMP '2017-10-17 00:00:00' AS record_time, 2 AS level UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2017-10-16 00:00:00', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2017-10-16 00:00:00', 4
)
SELECT
 id, record_time, level, lag,
 (level - lag) as diff
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, record_time, level, 
    LAG(level) OVER (ORDER BY id, record_time) as lag
  FROM Input
)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC;
```

Comment: I did not enable the standard SQL. I can't do that because I have another and big part of my query working on legacy SQL. And I have to access many views that do not allow an easy access by standard SQL. I thought out that this subtraction was possible in legacy mode.

Comment: I don't think you can use complex expressions with an OVER clause using legacy SQL. You need either to use standard SQL or do the analytic function computation in a subquery.

Comment: The LAG function with OVER clause in line 7 of my working query works very well in legacy mode. So, I just tried to optimize the query as I explained in my question but in a subtraction as in the second query in my question, it not works on legacy mode.