# How to get the number of days between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where I need to find the number of days that have passed between two rows with date fields. The rows that the calculation needs to be made are not sorted.

Here is the structure of the table

```
Folio   DATE    

1       6/1/2015
2       4/1/2015
1       3/1/2015
4       2/1/2015
1       1/1/2015
```

Basically, I would need to sort by date and keep only the last two transactions grouped by folio. so in this example, the transaction by folio 1 on 1/1/2015 would be ignored.

Suppose that I need to do the following:
1. Group by folio number
2. only count the days between the last two transactions by folio. For example, folio #1 would only include the transactions from 6/1/2015 and 3/1/2015.

The result I'm looking for:

```
Folio   FirstDATE   LastDate   #ofDays

1       3/1/2015     6/1/2015    90
```

Any MySQL pros out there? My skills are still in newbie territory. Thank you!

UPDATE:

I've managed to come up with the following:

```
SELECT 
  SubQuery.`Folio Number`,
  SubQuery.LatestClosing,
  SubQuery.FirstClosing,
  DATEDIFF(SubQuery.LatestClosing, SubQuery.FirstClosing) AS numofdays
FROM (SELECT
    Subquery.`Folio Number`,
    SubQuery.LatestClosing,
    SubQuery.FirstClosing
  FROM (SELECT t.`Folio Number`,
      MAX(t.`Closing Date`) AS LatestClosing,
      (SELECT
          s.`Closing Date`
        FROM MLSFinalimport s
        WHERE t.`Folio Number` = s.`Folio Number`
        ORDER BY s.`Closing Date` DESC
        LIMIT 1, 1) AS FirstClosing,
    FROM MLSFinalimport t
    GROUP BY t.`Folio Number`) SubQuery) SubQuery
```

This is generating a result that looks like this:

```
LatestClosing     First Closing   numofdays
7/20/2016         5/9/2006         3725
```

This is what I need. However, I'm stuck trying to add the original column for each row called "Folio Number". How do I proceed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows

Comment: Check out the link and you can find so many resources in google  MySQL DATE_ADD() Function - W3Schools
www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp
.

Comment: If you are expecting 90 days between 01-March-2015 and 01-June-2015 then you work on a different calendar to me... There are 92 days between those dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros for MySQL at this? Probably the opposite.. MySQL doesn't support window functions so you can try using a correlated query with `LIMIT/OFFSET`:

```
SELECT p.folio,p.max_d,p.second_d,DATEDIFF(p.max_d,p.second_d) as NumOfDays
FROM (
    SELECT t.folio,MAX(t.date) as max_d,
           (SELECT s.date FROM YourTable s
            WHERE t.folio = s.folio
            ORDER BY s.date DESC
            LIMIT 1,1) as second_d
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY t.folio) p
```

Comment: it's the american date, I think ;)

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify....

t.folio is the name of my table...

t.date is the current date field

s.date is?
s.folio is?

Are these aliases that create the modified columns? thank you

Comment: As you can see I'm selecting from your table twice, each time I aliased it differently, one time as `s`, and one time as `t` . The `t` alias is the leading table(which means the max date), and the `s` alias is to fetch the second date . `p` is the alias of the outcome of the inner query .

Comment: @sagi I went ahead and updated my original question with my results. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Update your question, not my answer. @user2041357

Comment: Add `subquery.fbaths` both  in the most outer select and in the middle one.

Comment: I.ve spent the last 30 minutes trying to place the sub query.fbaths correctly and I just can't get it to work

Comment: I've edited the query in your question, it should be fine now. @user2041357

Comment: Sagi, I'm running your code, but i'm getting the following error:

2 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(t.`Closing Date`) AS LatestClosing,
      (SELECT
          s.`Closing Dat' at line 11 Query2.sql 1 1

Comment: Missed a comma.. Now @user2041357

Comment: That fixed the error, but now I get this:

 Error (1,1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM MLSFinalimport 
    GROUP BY t.`Folio Number`) SubQuery) SubQuery limit 0,' at line 18