# Possible way to query mysql for calculate total time worked in a day

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to come up with the best way to add the total time an employee was clocked.

The INOUT types are S & E.

I was thinking something like this might be the best solution, but I don't know if it's practical or even possible:

For example:

```
No  EnNo    INOUT   DateTime
1   12      S       2017-06-02 08:35
2   28      S       2017-06-02 10:10
3   28      E       2017-06-02 13:00
4   12      E       2017-06-02 14:02
5   12      S       2017-06-02 15:03
6   12      E       2017-06-02 18:09
```

So In this example .I could try to calculate the total time work Hours. Again, I don't know if this is even possible.

I would REALLY appreciate any comments/suggestions in regards to how to accomplish this, or any other ways that might be more practical to do this!

Query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT EnNo, 
            sum(case 
            when INOUT = 'E' then -DATEDIFF(MINUTE,2017-06-02,DateTime)
            when INOUT = 'S' then  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,2017-06-02,DateTime) 
            end 
            )/60 as Working Hours 
        From `dataimport`
        Group By dataimport.EnNo";
```

But result is not produce..

Comment: You might want to check you incomplete usage of backticks

Comment: In this case,you have to fire query that return record with `INOUT='S'` and fir sub-query for get which have E and greater than that S record and then calculate the difference and then you will get work hours

Comment: I suggest that you should do some change in your table structure for better and fast result

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Something that could work is to select the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` between the two employees. You do have to join the table on itself in such a way that you have the difference between two records of employees that have a S and an E and on the same day.

I tried myself and came up with the following without testing, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT 
A.EnNo, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.DateTime,B.DateTime)/60 AS WorkingHours
FROM dataimport A INNER JOIN dataimport B ON A.EnNo = B.EnNo AND 
(A.INOUT = 'E' AND B.INOUT = 'S') OR  (A.INOUT = 'S' AND B.INOUT = 'E') 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,A.DateTime,B.DateTime) = 0
```

Note: you can also change the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to find the difference in hours in one go.

> References: [Calculate the time difference between of two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows)
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 0):

Also one simple way to calculate in php!!!

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-06-02 08:35');

$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-06-02 14:02');

$duration = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $duration->format('%h')." Hours ".$duration->format('%i')." Minutes";

Answer (score 0):

Please check the query twice and try with your code ...i have done same scenario which you have

```
$query->select("a.*,a.DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') as `new_date`,
                            DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:00') as `last_datetime`,
                            DATE_FORMAT(a.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d 00:01:00') as `first_datetime`,
                    @last_value:=(SELECT date_time FROM master a2
                    WHERE  a2.enroll=a.enroll
                    and (a2.INOUT = 'E' )
                    and (a2.`date_time` <= last_datetime and a2.`date_time`>first_datetime)
                    group by a2.date_time
                    ORDER BY a2.date_time DESC LIMIT 1) as last_value,



            ");
        $query->from('master as a')

        ->andWhere('a.enroll IS NOT NULL and a.INOUT="S"')
        ->groupBy('a.enroll,new_date')
        ->orderBy('a.enroll,a.date_time');
        $attendence_db_data = $query->all();
```

You will get user's first IN And last OUT of particular one day in one record so that you can easily calculate his/her work hour from that value.