# Calculating time difference between of two rows when primary key is not consecutive. How?

Tags: mysql

After much review I have identified what I believe to be the problem with a working query.

The MySQL query below is used to get the time difference between 2 records in a table. Everything works fine if the table only has one user id AND primary keys are consecutive.

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       UTL_TASK,
       SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS UTL_DURATION_TOTAL       
  FROM (

SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_TASK,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465615'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/
       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2019-03-04' AND '2019-03-12' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'

  /* Our derived table... */
) AS tbl_derived_1

GROUP BY USER_ID, UTL_TASK;
```

**Working scenario sample:**

[image: working]

**Non Working scenario sample:**

As you can see, the first orange entry in this example needs to subtract from the clock out entry stamp because it is the last stamp before clock out. Instead, the query is literally subtracting from the next in line???!!!

[image: nonworking]

How can I modify this query to take into account the following conditions:

A. The next consecutive record and respective time stamp inserted may or may not be added by the same user id. When it is not by the same user id, the query proceeds to just add the next record in line.

Basically, even when I try to filter by USER_ID 465615, the query just proceeds to add the next record in line whether it belongs to this user id or not.

Why?

**Here's is the closest I was able to find** on this site to possibly resolve this discrepancy.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937333/687137

Disclaimer: *This link does not constitute a duplicate. If you're just reading similar english words and feel like down voting without truly understanding the difference between what's on the site and this specific question, **move along**.*

Comment: With 26,400+ reputation on here ANYTHING is very simple.

Comment: That's not remotely true.

Comment: @ASPiRE : which version of MySQl are you using?

Comment: @GMB: Latest one.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide sample data as tabular text, because that allows others to actually test the queries they will try to provide. Also, would you please show the expected result for the second dataset?

Comment: Here's my only upvote. Yes. From now on, I shall post no examples without working examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just change your `JOIN` condition to:

```
INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
    ON B.UTL_DTSTAMP = (SELECT MIN(UTL_DTSTAMP)
                        FROM tbl_user_time_log C
                        WHERE C.USER_ID = A.USER_ID AND C.UTL_DTSTAMP > A.UTL_DTSTAMP)
   AND B.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
```

This will mean that only consecutive (time-wise) rows belonging to the same user will be used for the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` computation.

If you are using MySQL 8+, you can use [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) and remove the `JOIN` altogether:

```
...
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, LEAD(UTL_DTSTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY UTL_DTSTAMP)) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465615'
...
```

Comment: Thank you Nick. I am getting negative values on your first approach. Perhaps if you could post a full adaptation with my existing query? I've also updated the first picture to reflect precise date time stamps that match the second scenario.

Comment: @ASPiRE sorry I forgot `TIMESTAMPDIFF` did `expr2-expr1`, not the other way around. Have edited to compensate.

Comment: Does `WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465615'` become obsolete?

Comment: @ASPiRE if you want to return results for all users, yes

Comment: Ok. So it's not redundant. It's optional. Thank you for everything. I wish this question would have more points for everyone to see your solution. This is hard to find. I'll work on the updated post with proper examples.