# SQL Server: how to compare datetimes between rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2017 and I have a problem I didn't figure out how to build a query to solve it.

Let's say I have a table like this:

[image]

I have a same ID here is 97 I want to compare all datetimes that have the same 'NU_NUMBT' which is 97 in my case but with different 'NU_ORD' to calculate the `SUM` of `stopTime` of the `NU_NUMBT` as shown.

Example:

[image]

To calculate my sum of time difference the `DT_DATDEB` of the second row mustn't be between `DT_DATDEB` and `DT_DATFIN` of the first row

I can use 'NOT BETWEEN' but I want to fix the same `NU_NUMBT`  because I have many other numbers so that I cant calculate the sum for each `NU_NUMBT`

How can I deal with that please?

Comment: So what is your expected output here? Can you post your data as formatted `text`, or DDL and DML please? Images are less than ideal when the information we're dealing with is text. Also, if you are wanting to look at the values of the next/previous row, have you have a look at `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Comment: @Larnu I want to calculate the DATTDIF between DT_DATFIN and DT_DATDEB witch is stopTime as shownafter that i want to calculate the SUM(StopTime) in case there is not time overlap

Comment: possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows

Comment: You say that "the DT_DATDEB of the second row mustn't be between DT_DATDEB and DT_DATFIN of the first row", and you "want to calculate the SUM(StopTime) in case there is not time overlap". But in this case since there IS an overlap, how do you want to handle it? Do you want to exclude the amount of overlap between these spans from the sum of the StopTime column?

Comment: @Thermos That's it I want to exclude the overlap's amount from the sum of the Stop Time

Comment: For the sake of the question are we assuming that in other cases there would be values in all three rows for DT_DATDEB, DT_DATFIN, and StopTime? Seeing as we can't do anything with a row if there is a NULL in any of these columns...

Comment: @Thermos all rows will be with values other then NULL